# Does AsReadOnly make sense if you cast it in an IEnumerable eventually?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I saw some code in [this](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb) project that got my attention.

There is a simple method that calls AsReadOnly on a List. Instead of doing something with the ReadOnlyCollection the method returns it immediately and implicitly casts it into an IEnumerable.

What is the point of using AsReadOnly if you only need an Enumerable?

Would  AsEnumerable be a better option?

```
private List<PaymentMethod> _paymentMethods = new List<PaymentMethod>();

public IEnumerable<PaymentMethod> PaymentMethods => 
        _paymentMethods.AsReadOnly();
```

Comment: Let me ask you this:  can `PaymentMethods` be cast back to a `List<PaymentMethod>` and modified?

Comment: Yeah you are right. Someone could cast the return value of the method back to a List<PaymentMethod> and modify it which could be a potential danger.
Thanks for the question, so I had to think about it myself. 
I'm kinda new to all that stuff, thus I'm very grateful for the quick response!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the point of using `AsReadOnly` if you only need an enumerable?

The point is that `AsReadOnly` ensures that a low-trust hostile or buggy caller cannot cast back to a mutable collection.

> Would `AsEnumerable` be a better option?

No. Try this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>{ 10, 20, 30 };
...
IEnumerable<int> seq = list.AsEnumerable();
// Or (IEnumerable<int>)list, or whatever.
...
List<int> list2 = (List<int>)seq;
list2[0] = 40;
```

And now we have changed `list[0]`.

But `AsReadOnly` prevents this, as the read-only wrapper cannot be cast back to `List<int>`.

Remember, `AsEnumerable` is just a visually nicer way to write a cast, and casts that are reference conversions are *reference conversions*.  The reference is not changed and it can be changed back to its actual type!

Of course, a hostile or buggy caller that has full trust can arbitrarily break the safety system, because full trust means *full trust*. A read only collection maintains a reference to the original collection, and that reference can be retrieved via reflection.

Also, remember that read-only means *read-only*, not *unchanging*.  A read-only wrapper around a mutable collection can still be *observed* to change; you just cannot change it *via the read-only wrapper*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Amy indicicated the same thing with her post and both of you are right of course!

Comment: If you want to take a shallow clone of the `List<>` and then wrap the clone, you can do `_paymentMethods.ToList().AsReadOnly();`. Then no-one else will have a reference to the underlying collection. Of course, someone could still obtain that reference with reflection, as before.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Right, or just omit the `AsReadOnly` and hand out a mutable copy; if the caller mutates the copy, they're allowed to. But that then means that if you have data that never changes, you still have to make a copy every time you hand it out, which is wasteful.

Comment: @Nick: You are welcome. This design consideration factored into the design of LINQ. In LINQ if you have `x = from y in z select y;` that compiles into `x = z.Select(y => y);` which does not have referential identity with `z`. But `x = from y in z where p(y) select y;` compiles into `x = z.Where(y => p(y));` -- no `Select` -- because the compiler knows that the redundant `Select` is not needed in order to ensure that the reference is different!